# Retrieve SubItem from a "ToList();" in Lambda

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a list of users that i get from my database using a Lambda expression. The code should look like this:

```
var items = db.User.Where(x => x.User_id < 10).ToList();
```

But this complement "ToList();" wont let me get to the subitems when i try to invoke them with

```
items.User_Name
```

Only when i use the `.FirstOrDefault();` suffix.

There's anyway to create a list of elements with lambda and still be able to reach it's subitems?

Comment: What if you do `db.User.Include(x => x.User_Name).Where(x => x.User_id < 10).ToList();`?

Comment: you need to specify the index in the collection. Like items[0].User_Name

Comment: Your `items` is a collection. So doing `items.User_Name` is going to try and get a `User_Name` property off of an `IEnumerable<User>`, which doesn't exist. You need to inspect a single item in the collection, which is what `FirstOrDefault()` gives you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Items` variable is a `List`. `List` does not have property named `User_Name`.
If you want to get a `User_Name` of single item, you can use `.FirstOrDefault();` as you mentioned or access items by `index` like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(items[1234].User_Name)
```

If you want to get a list of `User_Names` you can use `Select` when you read your data:

```
db.User.Where(x => x.User_id < 10).Select(x => x.User_Name).ToList();
```

This way you get a list of user names.

You can read more about `Lists` in [msdn docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8). More about `Select` also in [msdn docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you cannot get a User_Name from a list of Users. You can either get a User_Name from a specific User object in that list, e.g. via items.FirstOrDefault().User_Name; like you mentioned gets you the first User in the list and returns their User_Name. Or you could do items[2].User_Name to get the 3rd User's User_Name from that list.

Or if what you mean by "sub items" is that you want a list of just User_Names, then you need the select statement:

```
var userNames = db.User.Where(x => x.User_id < 10).Select(x => x.User_Name).ToList();
```